# How make accordion in 2 columns ( Link on left content to right)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a in 2 columns the content will show right column while the content is on the right column.

I tried to make it using this code

```
<dl class="accordion">
   <div class="col-sm-6 mb-sm-50 pt-70 mb-xs-30">
      <dt>
         <a href="">First</a>
      </dt>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 mb-sm-50 pt-70 mb-xs-30">
      <dd>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.
      </dd>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 mb-sm-50 pt-70 mb-xs-30">
      <dt>
         <a href="">Second</a>
      </dt>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 mb-sm-50 pt-70 mb-xs-30">
      <dd>
         Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.
      </dd>
   </div>
</dl>
<!-- End Accordion -->
```

but it seems not not working but when in 1 column it works.

anyone can help me??

Comment: do you use bootstrap framework or just plain css ?

Comment: i use bootstrap\